# How could one use OpenCV to count isolated white spots in below image for each circle in the circle grid?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, opencv, hough-transform, object-recognition, python

I can detect the spots using houghcircles function in opencv:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,0.1,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=1,maxRadius=40)
```

[image]

This can be further improved with image segmentation and watershed I guess for segmenting the fused spots to some extent. However, I would like to count each of those non-merged white spots as per the circle grid above it and get a count of white spots belonging to circle 1, circle2,...,circle96.

I would welcome suggestions on how that could be achieved.

I had tried canny edge, but it detects too many edges for the plate.